# Robotics library in Forth?

Tags: robotics, forth

I have read the documentation for the Roboforth environment from [STrobotics](http://www.strobotics.com/) and recognized that this a nice way for programming a robot. What I missed is a sophisticated software library with predefined motion primitives. For example, for picking up a object, for regrasping or for changing a tool.

In other programming languages like Python or C++, a library is a convenient way for programming repetitive tasks and for storing expert knowledge into machine-readable files. Also a library is good way for not-so-talented programmers to get access on higher-level-functions. In my opinion Forth is the perfect language for implementing such an API, but I didn't find information about it. Where should I search? Are there any examples out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am author of RoboForth, and you make a good point. I have approached the problem of starting off new users with videos on YouTube; see [How to...](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBcXpOAbOrG3pnlRlJDISQmWOVJP9xX3L) (playlist with 6 items, e.g "ST Robotics How-to number 1 - getting started") which is a playlist covering basics and indeed tool changing.

I never wrote any starter programs, because the physical positions (coordinates) would be different from one user to the next, however I think it can be done, and I will do it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: IMHO the concept of creating forth words (=motion primitives) is powerfull enough to program a unimate robot from 1960s to serve a cup of tea. Isnt't it?

Comment: There is a famous picture of George Devol and Joseph Engelberger being served drinks by a Unimate.

Comment: On YouTube, can you make the title of the playlist more specific/descriptive?

Comment: That is a very good idea. I've added a description and may edit it a tad better later. Thanks. Let me have any feedback or criticisms.